# How can I fix all vulnerabilities in my package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am working on a login/registration form using MongoDB, Express, Passport, Bcrypt.js, among other things.

When I run 'npm i' it tells me I have vulnerabilities, I cloned the file and ran **'npm audit fix'**, it worked! But it didn't fix all the vulnerabilities, so I ran **'npm audit fix --force'** on the cloned file and it broke. How can I fix these vulnerabilities without breaking my code?

Comment: Might be helpful to list the module names and versions you had before and after the fix - that way this becomes a reproducible issue.

Comment: The way I read it, you asked the same question here:
[How do I safely run 'npm audit fix --force'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74397479)
That other question is ***much*** better because there you include your
`package.json` file.
Without `package.json`, it's effectively impossible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I safely run 'npm audit fix --force'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397479/how-do-i-safely-run-npm-audit-fix-force)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "npm audit fix" didn't fix all the issues, it probably means the vulnerabilities were fixed in a major version. You'll need to see if the remaining packages with vulnerabilities have migration guides, as major versions mean there are breaking changes.

Although if they're all dev dependancies, you might be able to get away with ignoring the warnings.